# Ошибка Unknown label type: 'continuous' при обучении kNN

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Обучаю метод ближайших соседей.
На обычном DataFrame из признаков все работает хорошо. Но, когда я масштабирую признаки возникает ошибка.

Вот код:

```
y = data['Sort'].astype(float)
X = data.drop('Sort', axis=1)
X = data.astype(float)
X_scale = sk.preprocessing.scale(X)
y_scale = sk.preprocessing.scale(y)
```

Вывожу оптимальное количество соседей и оценку работы алгоритма:

```
kMeans_scale = []
for k in range(1,51):
    kn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
    kn.fit(X_scale, y_scale)
    array = cross_val_score(estimator = kn, X=X_scale, y=y_scale, cv=kf, scoring = 'accuracy')
    kMeans_scale.append(m)
m = max(kMeans_scale)
print(np.round(m,decimals = 2))
s = kMeans_scale.index(m)
print(s+1)
```

Ошибка:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-134-af5b3598c259> in <module>
      2 for k in range(1,51):
      3     kn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
----> 4     kn.fit(X_scale, y_scale)
      5     array = cross_val_score(estimator = kn, X=X_scale, y=y_scale, cv=kf, scoring = 'accuracy')
      6     kMeans_scale.append(m)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py in fit(self, X, y)
    903             self.outputs_2d_ = True
    904 
--> 905         check_classification_targets(y)
    906         self.classes_ = []
    907         self._y = np.empty(y.shape, dtype=np.int)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    169     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    170                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 171         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
    172 
    173
```

С чем это может быть связано?

> ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Искомый столбец `y` масштабировать не надо. Тем самым вы превращаете классы (целые дискретные числа) в вещественные числа. Это не дает никакого выигрыша и кроме того вам придется декодировать масштабированные метки обратно в исходные классы.

Answer (score 2):

Удалите:

```
y_scale = sk.preprocessing.scale(y)
```